# Ninja Form custom addon diplaying line number in submissions

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms, ninja

i tried to create my own addon ninja form. I do what I could knowing that the documentation on the subject is non-existent but I have an annoying problem, I actually created a nf field allowing file upload via a nf form, I want to display the file link in ninja form entries but line numbers are automatically added instead of simply displaying the link of the file.

Do you have any idea how to suppress this display maybe with parameters for my field class which extends from NF_Abstracts_Field ?

here are the variables of my custom class :

```
protected $_name = 'file_upload';
protected $_type = 'file_upload';
protected $_nicename = 'File Upload';
protected $_section = 'common';
protected $_icon = 'file';
protected $_test_value = false;
protected $_templates = ['fileupload'];
```

I tried to compare the output values ​​for a traditional textbox field with my custom field but without success

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution by using this filter :

```
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_custom_columns', array($this, 'custom_columns'), 10, 2 );
```

but it works only if i activate "old submission page" in ninja form settings